# Testing user role , Authorize attribute in VB.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I am using ASP.NET MVC to build a site. I am using VB as programming language.I have couple of questions.

1 I have created a role "Manager". How Do I check if a user belongs to this particular role?

For now I am using

```
If My.User.IsInRole("Manager") Then

'Direct to a view
Else
'Direct to another view
End If
```

Is this the right way?

2 How to use the Authorize attribute to limit access to a Function?

I know in C# it goes `[Authorize (Roles ="Manager")]` but not sure in VB.

Also can I define property to redirect a user who does not have "Manager" role to a particular view when trying to access this function .

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

in vb it would be:

```
<Authorize(Roles := "Manager")> _
```

Comment: Thanks. Can I define some where to redirect the unauthorized user to a particular view?

Comment: @fireBand: Did you ever find an answer to the redirect question?

Comment: I'm going to try and find an answer (as I am looking too) to help the next person...

Comment: http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security/membership/user-based-authorization-vb will redirect to another page if the access level is denied.